# How to retrieve the latest created object in playframework

Tags: java, playframework

If the model class does not contain a creation_time field, is it possible to retrieve the latest created object?

Suppose there is an `Address` class which contains a number of String fields and no creation date. If a user created an address1 yesterday and then he creates another address today, how do I retrieve the one created today?  I think django has a way to do this by means of `pk of the record in db`.

Something like

```
Model.objects.latest('pk')
```

Is there a similar facility in playframework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an assumption (ie, ensure) that the id is sequential then you can do something like this:

```
Address.find("username = ? order by id desc", "%username%").fetch(1);
```

This should retrieve the first entry when sorted by ID which should be the most recent entry. As play uses hibernate/JPA you may find a better answer if you ask this question as a generic JPA/Hibernate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

```
Estimate.find("order by id desc").first();
```

this returns the last object